# How to foreach every figure in a number?

Tags: c#

I want to make a program to reverse a number and the program to sayed every even digit in a number.
I tried to make something like that, I search on Google but i observe i can't and i need a little help.

```
do
{
    int number, reverse= 0, a;
        Console.WriteLine("Introdu un numar de 10 cifre:");
       number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    while(number>0)
    {
        a = number % 10;
        reverse = (reverse* 10) + a;
        number = number / 10;
    }       
    int[] array = new int[] {reverse};
    foreach (int evennfigure in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(evennfigure);
    }
} while (true);
```

Comment: The answer is in understanding division and modulus ... and loops. Look those up. Division you know. Modulus is "remainder". Put those together with the number 10 and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Whoever upvoted the question, could you please [edit] the question to clarify what OP needs help with?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - questions from new users get an automatic up vote

Comment: @RandRandom sorry, I don't think I'm smart enough to understand your comment. If you tried to joke - consider smiley, if it is your personal policy - maybe reconsider that, if you consider that to be site's policy - consider finding supporting link.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(int.TryParse(new string(Console.ReadLine().Reverse().ToArray()), out var number)?number.ToString():"not an int");`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
IEnumerable<int> Reverse(int n)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        yield return n % 10;
        foreach (int x in Reverse(n / 10))
            yield return x;
    }
}
```

When I call `Reverse(10532)` I get the following:

```
2 
3 
5 
0 
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have reversed number. I add to you code part that find even digits.

```
do
{
    int number=0, reverse= 0, a;
    var evens = "";
    Console.WriteLine("Introdu un numar de 10 cifre:");
    try
    {
       number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not number");
        continue;
    }

    while(number>0)
    {
        a = number % 10;
        reverse = (reverse* 10) + a;
        number = number / 10;
            
        if(a % 2 == 0) //check if digit is even
            evens += $", {a}";  //form string with even digits
    }       
            
    Console.WriteLine($"Reverse: {reverse}");

    evens = string.IsNullOrEmpty(evens) ? "not exist" : evens.Trim(',');
    Console.WriteLine($"Even digits: {evens}");         
} while (true);
```

My code show all even digits. If you want only unique even digits, you should write this checking.